# How to call an Oracle function of refcursor return type using sqlalchemy and python

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, sqlalchemy, plsqldeveloper

### Function is given below:

```
CREATE or replace function get_data(data_key integer) return sys_refcursor 
is
result1 sys_refcursor;
BEGIN

open result1 for 'Select DISTINCT COL1
        FROM REF_TABLE
        where DATA_KEY='||data_key;

return result1;
END;
```

### Calling of the above function

```
variable rc refcursor;
exec :rc :=get_data(30038);
print rc;
```

This is working fine from sql developer. 
How to call the same using python and sqlalchemy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I used cx_Oracle instead of SQLAlchemy and it worked. Result output is same what I was expecting from sqlalchemy. I converted the function to procedure.**

### Procedure

```
CREATE or replace procedure get_data(data_key in integer, result out 
sys_refcursor) as
BEGIN

open result for 'Select DISTINCT COL1
        FROM ref_table
        where DATA_KEY='||data_key;

END;
```

### Code for calling the above procedure using python and cx_Oracle

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('system/<password>@127.0.0.1/XE')
cur = conn.cursor()

myvar = cur.var(cx_Oracle.CURSOR)
cur.callproc('get_data', (30038, myvar))
data = myvar.getvalue().fetchall()
if len(data) == 0:
    data = {}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[i[0] for i in myvar.getvalue().description])
print df
```

Output of the above code

```
                      COL1
--------------------------
0                   219586
1                   246751
2                   228245
3                   244517
4                   220765
5                   243467
6                   246622
7                   222784
```